# Function returning table

Tags: plpgsql

I want a plpgsql function that returns the content of any table, given the name. The function below, although not working because of many reasons will gove you the general idea. Safety and coding practice aside, what's the easiest way to accomplish this?

In the end I want to get these results trough a Java CallableStatement.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_table(tablename VARCHAR)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $PROC$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM tablename;
END;
$PROC$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your function working like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_table(tablename VARCHAR)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $PROC$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' || quote_ident(tablename);
END;
$PROC$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

In order to call it, you must specify names and data types for all returned columns.  If you want to list table "t" which has two columns, you could use your function like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM get_table('t') x(id int, val text);
```

Which of course, is longer and a lot more trouble than either:

```sql
SELECT * FROM t;
```

or the equivalent:

```sql
TABLE t;
```

I really can't imagine a use-case where such a function makes anything better.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this is useful in my situation where we have different schemas set up for different users, but the reporting system that we have doesn't allow us to change the `search_path` properly. This allows the workaround of passing a query into a function, and the function sets the `search_path` appropriately, then runs the query and returns the result. (And the `RETURN QUERY` doesn't allow multiple queries or non select queries, helping to keep it safe.)